# Find closest node that matches criteria but cannot have intermediary nodes that have certain properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following criteria:

1. From a starting node with an internal ID of X, I want to grab the closest `WorkOrderNode` that has an `action_code` of "INS".
2. However, between those two nodes, there can be an arbitrary number of nodes, and I need to make sure these intermediary nodes are not `WorkOrderNode`s that have `action_code`s other than "MV" or "SPT".

Here is my latest attempt:

```
MATCH p=(a)<-[*]-(b:WorkOrderNode {action_code: 'INS'})
WHERE ID(a)=105
RETURN b, size(relationships(p)) as distance
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 1
```

This fulfills the 1st criteria but I'm having problems implementing the 2nd criteria. I tried using `AND NOT EXISTS((b)-[*]->(c:WorkOrderNode) WHERE c.action_code NOT IN ['MV', 'SPT']` in the parent `WHERE` clause but neo4j throws an error because I can't have a `WHERE` clause in an `EXISTS` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be the most optimized, but I would try the following:

```
MATCH p=(a)<-[*]-(b:WorkOrderNode {action_code: 'INS'})
WHERE ID(a)=105 AND 
NONE(node IN nodes(p) WHERE node:WorkOrderNode AND node.action_code IN ['MV', 'SPT'])
RETURN b, length(p) as distance
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hey, can you take a look at this [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68615940/not-operator-fails-to-filter-as-expected-in-cypher-query) I have posed? For some reason, your answer didn't work on a different test case. I must have gotten a false positive when I tested your code Friday.