# NOT operator fails to filter as expected in cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm having trouble getting the `NOT` operator to work in my cypher query.

The following query works and returns a result:

```
MATCH p=(a)<-[*]-(b:WorkOrderNode)
WHERE ID(a)=107
AND b.action_code='INS'
AND NONE(x in nodes(p) WHERE exists(x.action_code) AND x.action_code='PULL')
RETURN b
```

However, this query is not that effective for my business logic because there can be an arbitrary number of actions, so what I really want is to exclude any paths where there may be a node with a work action **other than** 'MV' or 'SPT' (work action is not 'MV' or 'SPT').

Hence, I update my code to:

```
MATCH p=(a)<-[*]-(b:WorkOrderNode)
WHERE ID(a)=107
AND b.action_code='INS'
AND NONE(x in nodes(p) WHERE exists(x.action_code) AND NOT x.action_code IN ['MV', 'SPT'])
RETURN b
```

But the problem is that there are no results returned for this query.

These two statements should be logically equivalent? `x.action_code='PULL'` ==(?) `NOT x.action_code IN ['MV', 'SPT']`

I also tried the following but it also doesn't work. There's something I'm obviously missing:

```
MATCH p=(a)<-[*]-(b:WorkOrderNode)
WHERE ID(a)=107
AND b.action_code='INS'
AND NONE(x in nodes(p) WHERE exists(x.action_code) AND (x.action_code <> 'MV' OR x.action_code <> 'SPT'))
RETURN b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to make sure that the final node of the path (b) always has b.action_code='INS' and none of the other nodes has 'INS', perhaps a better way would be to use

```
NONE(x in nodes(p)[..-1]    .....  NOT x.action_code in ['MV', 'SPT'])
```

instead of

```
NONE(x in nodes(p) ...
```

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. I actually want the nearest node with work action `INS` to (a) and your solution would definitely solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, silly me.

The problem is not in the logical equivalence between the two statements (`x.action_code='PULL'` and `NOT x.action_code IN ['MV', 'SPT']`).

It's due to the conflict between `WHERE b.action_code='INS'` and `NOT x.action_code IN ['MV', 'SPT']`. Since the path I'm interested in consists of WorkOrderNodes that have `INS` work actions, by not including them in the action list would remove all paths found in the previous conditions.

This is the solution:

```
MATCH p=(a)<-[*]-(b:WorkOrderNode)
WHERE ID(a)=107
AND b.action_code='INS'
AND NONE(x in nodes(p) WHERE exists(x.action_code) AND NOT x.action_code in ['MV', 'SPT', 'INS'])
RETURN b
```